# Visual Studio Community 2015 SQL - how to populate a schema with test data

Tags: visual-studio

Using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 to create a SQL Database.

I haven't constructed a SQL database for maybe 15 years or more, and now I'm falling at the first hurdle.

How do I populate a schema with test data?

I have at the moment the following in my SQL Server Object Explorer panel: two default SQL servers listed (MSSQLocalDB and ProjectsV13 - both marked as localdb), and the current project with tables.

I have no problems in creating tables, but no way apparently to populate them with test data.

What do I need to do? Sorry for the very dumb question.

Comment: Upgrade to VS2017. Use the View Data menu option on a selected table. You can edit the table or use the script icon on the menu bar to create and execute an insert script.

Comment: Thank you. I would prefer to use 2017 than 2015, but I don't seem to be getting SQL at all on the former, and had rather assumed it wasn't yet ready. I shall look again at what I've downloaded. If you have any suggestion as to what I might have missed in downloads, would be grateful for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a database project, create an SQL script in your database project and populate it manually with a good amount of sample data (use your discretion) using SQL `INSERT INTO` queries.

[See here for INSERT statements](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)

Comment: Thank you. I shall try that out tomorrow.